# Use MDF with entityframework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, scaffolding

I'm trying to figure out how to connect to an .mdf file using entityframework core.  I found a resource on how to connect to one [here](https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2018/02/using-an-mdf-file-database-with-entity-framework-core-2-in-visual-studio-2017/) However it doesn't seem to be working.  I've made a var simple context using the Northwind dataset

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    // etc.
}

public class NorthwindContext : DbContext
{
    public NorthwindContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

I've created a test class to attempt to connect to the DB

```
public string NorthwindConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                      AttachDbFilename=C:\source\Astoot\RestEzCore.Tests\TestDB\NORTHWND.MDF;
                      Integrated Security=True;
                      Connect Timeout=30;
                      User Instance=True";

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<NorthwindContext>();
    //I've also tried UseSqlLite()
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(this.NorthwindConnectionString);
    using (var context = new NorthwindContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
    {
        var orders = context.Orders.ToList();
        Assert.IsTrue(orders.Any());
    }
}
```

However when I attempt to run my tests I get an error

> instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

**Edit**

I've also tried moving my MDF to users folder and connect using this connection string:

> Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;DataBase=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

However this doesn't seem to work as well, it throws an exception

> SqlException: Cannot open database "Northwind" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'MyUser'

Is there something wrong with my connection string?

I can't quite seem to figure out how to use an MDF with entityframework

Comment: Can you try \\ in path  C:\source\Astoot\RestEzCore.Tests\TestDB\NORTHWND.MDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some investigation, and it turns out that it was returning a bogus error because Northwind DB in built from SQL Server 2000, and I'm running SQL server 2016 so Instead I Created a Sample DB and used that as an MDF.

Now my connection string looks like so:

```
public static string MDF_Directory
{
    get
    {
        var directoryPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(directoryPath, "..//..//..//TestDB"));
    }
}

public string astootConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; " +
        "AttachDbFilename="+ MDF_Directory + "\\Astoot.mdf;" +
        " Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=30;";
```

Comment: can i use on servers ?

Comment: You can use it where ever you want.  But should you, probably not its very inefficient